# How do I display 'ABCMeta' object with bottle?　What is the data type of fractions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

**I want to display fraction data type as bottle**

index.py

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from fractions import Fraction
from bottle import route, view

@route('/')
@view("index_template")

def index():
    f = Fraction(3, 4)
    return dict(type(f))
```

index.template

```
{{f}}
```

Apache error log

> TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not iterable

---

**environment**

・Cent OS 6
・Python 3.6
・Apache 2.2
・mod_wsgi-4.5
・bottle 0.13
・Chrome 62

Comment: What do you expect converting the `Fraction` type to a dictionary to do? Neither the class nor its instances are iterable (as `dict()` expects).

Comment: I just want to display the type result in bottle. The reason for using dict (type (f)) is because nothing was displayed when trying str (type (f))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a string representation of the Fraction object. E.g.,

```
@route('/')
def index():
    f = Fraction(3, 4)
    return str(f)
```

---

Also (just FYI): `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` is not necessary unless you include non-ascii characters in your source code.

---

**EDIT**: OP has indicated that s/he wants to return the *type* of the Fraction object, not its value. In that case just return the type (as a string).

```
@route('/')
def index():
    f = Fraction(3, 4)
    return str(type(f))
```

---

**EDIT #2**: OP is (I'm guessing) using a browser to test, and the response is being rendered as html, which is confusing the OP since the page appears blank. To work around this, I suggest returning a text response, like this:

```
from bottle import response

@route('/')
def index():
    f = Fraction(3, 4)
    response.content_type = 'text/plain' 
    return str(type(f))
```

Comment: How can I write in order to display <class 'fractions.Fraction'> in bottle?

Comment: You want to display the *type*, not the *value*? That is confusing, but okay, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: "return str(f)" display value.but "return str(type(f))" display nothing. What can be considered as a cause?

Comment: It's working, but you can't see it because you're using a browser. Try requesting it with curl or wget.

Comment: Or try `view source` in the browser.

Comment: When I tried it, I was able to display the expected results. Thank you!